# Replace all occurences in a (request param) string

Tags: regex, query-string

I have a request string in the http body like

```
param1=123&param2=asdf&param3=dsjf&param4=1234134&param5=29348
```

Now, I'd like to replace the value of param4 with 1111 (it's not ensured WHERE param4 occurs in the string; could be at the very beginning and end as well).

I try the following, but this doesn't work: replace `(.*)&(param4=[0-9]*)&(.*)` with `&$1param4=1111&$2`

as the resulting string from above is `param1=123&param2=asdf&param3=dsjf&amount=2&amount=1234134`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for:

```
([?&]param4)=[^&]*
```

And replace by:

```
$1=1111
```

Where `$1` is back reference to captured group #1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this :

search for    `(&?param4)=([^&]+)`  and replace by `\1=1111` or `$1=1111` depending on the language you are using .

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pF5xK6)**

Answer (score 1):

Find this:

```
(?<=[?&])param4=[^&]*
```

then replace by:

```
param4=1111
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/nX3oW6